# Parallel RC Circuit Time Constant

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors

For a general RC circuit that looks like the following:

[image]

(Sorry for the rough sketch of the circuit, I couldn't find a picture online)

What would the time constant or RC equations be?

My thinking:
The time constant would be R<sub>2</sub>C.

I drew a large loop around the circuit (contains battery, R<sub>2</sub> and C): So from  KVL I have : V - R<sub>2</sub> I<sub>2</sub> - Q(t)/C = 0  and solving the differential equation, I get that Q(t) = VC(1-e<sup>(-t/R<sub>2</sub>C)</sup>).

I'm not sure I'm right so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.  The parallel resistor R1 has no effect if the components are ideal.  If you are using a more realistic model of a battery as an ideal voltage source with some finite internal resistance then it would come into play.

Edit: however if you were to remove the battery and observe the time constant as the capacitor discharged through R1 and R2 the time constant would be different.

Comment: Thank you. I'd also like to confirm the max current in the current equation would thus be V/R_2 right?

Comment: Maximum current out of the battery when charging is V/R1 + V/R2 which decays to V/R1 with the time constant previously mentioned.

Comment: Yea. I was referring to the current in the branch that contains the capacitor though. Also how come the max current is V/R1+ V/R2? Should the max current occur when the capacitor has 0 charge? So I have 2 resistors in parallel which means my current is VR1R2/(R1+R2)?

Comment: Yes.  The current through R1 is always V/R1.  The current through R2 starts at V/R2 and drops to 0 as the capacitor charges up to V.  V/R1 + V/R2 is equal to V[R1R2/(R1+R2)].

Answer (score 1):

The time constant of a circuit is obtained by reducing the excitation or the stimulus to zero. Zeroing your voltage source is similar to replacing it by a short circuit in the network under study. Once done, temporarily disconnect the capacitor and "look" through its connecting terminals to determine the resistance R:

[image]

The pole, for a 1st-order circuit is the inverse of the time constant. For more information on time constants and poles, you can have a look at a [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) I taught in 2016 and available to download from my webpage.

Comment: How can this R = R1 + R2 be true?

Comment: Oh, it is not and needs a clean up! : ) Thanks for pointing out this miserable typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right.

For charging, it's R2 and C. For discharging, it would be R1+R2 and C.

Answer (score 0):

R1 is in parallel with an ideal voltage source. It has no effect, since ideal voltage sources have zero impedance. Paralleling a zero impedance with any other impedance doesn't change anything. The equivalent circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fofYoo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>